# $\dfrac{-1}{n} < x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\Rightarrow x\geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to show

$\dfrac{-1}{n} < x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\Rightarrow x\geq 0$

And I'am not allowed to use limits. Any ideas? I have tried to use contraposition, but with no luck.

Comment: Could you explain what you *are* allowed to use? If yo have a textbook, for example, it would be helpful to let us know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is clear: $x$ cannot be a negative real number since you can find a sufficiently large $n$ to squeeze $-\frac1n$ between it and zero. So it has to be non-negative. I guess the point of such an exercise is to write this in formal symbols.

Comment: This seems like circular reasoning.  I thought the point was essentially to prove that for every $x>0$, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n<x$, or equivalently, for every $y>0$, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>y$.  This merely asserts it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: At first I was inclined to agree with you, but, looking at the algebra-precalculus tag, I suppose it may well be that the Archimedean property can be assumed.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to saying that if $x<0$ then for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $-1/n\ge x$.  That is in turn equivalent to saying that for every $x>0$, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $1/n\le x$.  So let $c=\inf\{1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  Since $1/n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it must be that $c\ge 0$.  If we can prove that $c=0$, we're done, since that means every $x>0$ fails to be a lower bound.

So suppose $c>0$.  Then $0<c\le 1/n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  Since $c$ is the **greatest** lower bound, $2c$ is *not* a lower bound.  Therefore, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $1/n < 2c$.  But then $1/(2n) < c$, and since $2n\in\mathbb{N}$, this contradicts the fact that $c$ is a lower bound.

**Later edit:** I find it being asserted in other answers that it's enough to observe that for every real $y>0$, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>y$.  But I took that to be the thing to be proved.  I take $\mathbb{N}$ to be  a ring and assume the reals have the least-upper-bound property.  The problem is to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ has no upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$.  If it does, then it has a least upper bound $a$.  The smaller number $a/2$ is then *not* an upper bound.  Therefore for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>a/2$.  Since $2n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $2n>a$, the number $a$ is *not* an upper bound of $\mathbb{N}$ and we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write a little more improvised proof which is by @Micheal Hardy

The statement $\frac{\displaystyle -1}{\displaystyle n}< x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\implies x \geq 0$ is equivalent to  for every $x\geq0$ $\exists\  n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $x \geq \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle n}$ i.e $n\geq\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle x}$ . Let us assume that $n<\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle x}$ $\implies$ $\mathbb{N}$ has an upper bound which is absurd. So the given statement is proved.